# Is there a text editor with syntax highlighting for PGN files?

Tags: pgn

In Notepad++ or similar editors, one can get syntax highlighting for multiple file formats/languages. I'd like to have something usable on Windows that would let me do this with pgn files (see header tags, and annotations in different colors from main line moves).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notepad ++ with option Language->Pascal highlights headers, move numbers, actual moves and comments with different colors. Works exactly as I would expect.

Answer (score 10):

There is an extension for Vim (a great editor) that provides syntax highlighting for PGN. You can download Vim [here](http://www.vim.org/download.php). You can find the extension [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=677).

Comment: I have used this before and it works pretty well.  The only issue I see is if you are not used to `Vim`, it may take a bit.

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on `Vim` [here](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/) that is worth reading.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, Vim was not  my first pick. But it works. However it does not highlight textual annotations. Only move numbers and game header tags.